# How do I view more than two Chromium extension icons?

Tags: chromium, google-chrome-extensions

I've been using Chrome[ium] for a while now, I love it. However, some things bother me a lot. One of those is that I can only see two extension icons and my Omni-bar is so big I can type a whole paragraph in it. They sell the omni-bar on space savings, but it certainly seems like a large waste of space.

Is there a way to see more than two extensions at the expense of the obnoxiously sized omni-bar text box? I've discovered I can reorder by two extensions but the `»` icon that shows the rest of the extentions will not permit me to drag and drop to add them.

I'm using `Chromium 7.0.523.0 (59206) Ubuntu 10.04`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the Omnibar.

Comment: You know what, we don't have an icon for it in 7.0. That's really irritating -- but the answer really is that simple. The gap between the first icon and the start of the omnibar is dragable, without any UI hint other than the mouse changing if your over the zone.